Angular Material Custom Theme for Progress Spinner
I am trying to define a custom scheme for my progress spinner in angular material. Following the docs:
.my-custom-theme {
  $primary: mat.define-palette(mat.$red-palette);
  $theme: mat.define-light-theme($primary, $primary, $primary);
  
  @include mat.core-theme($theme);
  @include mat.all-component-colors($theme);
  @include mat.all-component-themes($theme);
  @include mat.all-component-typographies($theme)
}


<div class="my-custom-theme">
  <mat-spinner></mat-spinner>
  <button mat-flat-button>Test</button> // this is the right color as themed by 'my-custom-theme'
</div>

What am I missing for the progress spinner?  Its themed as my default theme for the project and not parents theme.  Whats weird is that the button however is themed correctly.

what version of angular and angular material?

Angular Material v14

issue not reproducible stackblitz please replicate and share back!
